# Adding Android Mobile Controller to Unity Game

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have been trying for quiet some time now to find out how can I place an android mobile game controller in Unity. The game I have is using the mouse and keyboard buttons to do that but because I want to publish it on Android as well I want to add mobile controllers and I am not very familiar with that.

Here is my PlayerController.cs:

```
public class PlayerControllerUnity : MonoBehaviour
{
public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;

public float sensitivityX = 15.0f;
public float sensitivityY = 15.0f;

public float minimumX = -360.0f;
public float maximumX = 360.0f;

public float minimumY = -89.0f;
public float maximumY = 89.0f;

private float rotationYaxis = 0.0f;
private float rotationXaxis = 0.0f;

private Quaternion originalCameraRotation;
private Quaternion originalPlayerRotation;

public PlayerUnity playerUnity;

private GameObject hand;

private GameObject goInHand;
private CWObject currentObjectInHand;

private Vector3 positionHand_Tile = new Vector3(0.15f, -0.15f, 0.3f);
private Vector3 scaleHand_Tile = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
private Quaternion rotationHand_Tile = Quaternion.Euler(-15.0f, 0.0f, 15.0f);

private Vector3 positionHand_Item = new Vector3(0.15f, -0.15f, 0.2f);
private Vector3 scaleHand_Item = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
private Quaternion rotationHand_Item = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 55.0f, 0.0f);

private Vector3 positionHand_Current;
private Vector3 scaleHand_Current;
private Quaternion rotationHand_Current;

private bool firstUpdate = true;

public void Start()
{
    originalCameraRotation = playerUnity.mainCamera.transform.localRotation;
    originalPlayerRotation = transform.localRotation;

    hand = new GameObject();
    hand.name = "Hand";

    hand.transform.parent = playerUnity.mainCamera.transform;

    hand.transform.localPosition = positionHand_Tile;
    hand.transform.localScale = scaleHand_Tile;
    hand.transform.localRotation = rotationHand_Tile;
}

public void UpdateControlled()
{
    if (playerUnity.gameManagerUnity.State == GameManagerUnity.GameManagerUnityState.GAME &&
        playerUnity.playerGUI.ActiveState == PlayerGUI.State.NORMAL)
    {
        if (Screen.lockCursor == false)
        {
            //Auto pause if the user leaves the game for some reason (ALT+TAB, etc..)
            playerUnity.gameManagerUnity.Pause();
        }
        else
        {
            if (firstUpdate)
            {
                rotationYaxis = playerUnity.player.rotation.y;
                rotationXaxis = playerUnity.player.rotation.x;
                firstUpdate = false;
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
                playerUnity.player.ResetPosition();

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
                playerUnity.ChangeCamera();

            UpdateJump();
            UpdateMovement();
            UpdateCameraRotation();
            UpdateUserActions();
            UpdateItemOnHand();

            playerUnity.player.rotation.y = rotationYaxis;
            playerUnity.player.rotation.x = rotationXaxis;
        }
    }
}

private void ExecuteHandUseAnimation()
{
    handUseAnimationTimer = 0.5f;
}

private float handUseAnimationTimer;
private float handMovementTimer;

private void UpdateItemOnHand()
{
    if (currentObjectInHand != playerUnity.objectInHand)
    {
        if (goInHand)
        {
            playerUnity.gameManagerUnity.objectsManagerUnity.RemoveGameObject(goInHand);

            goInHand = null;
        }

        this.currentObjectInHand = playerUnity.objectInHand;

        if (currentObjectInHand != null)
        {
            goInHand = playerUnity.gameManagerUnity.objectsManagerUnity.CreateGameObjectFromObject(currentObjectInHand);

            goInHand.transform.parent = hand.transform;
            goInHand.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            goInHand.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            goInHand.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;

            switch (currentObjectInHand.definition.type)
            {
                case CWDefinition.DefinitionType.Item:
                    positionHand_Current = positionHand_Item;
                    scaleHand_Current = scaleHand_Item;
                    rotationHand_Current = rotationHand_Item;
                    break;

                case CWDefinition.DefinitionType.Tile:
                    positionHand_Current = positionHand_Tile;
                    scaleHand_Current = scaleHand_Tile;
                    rotationHand_Current = rotationHand_Tile;
                    break;
            }

            hand.transform.localPosition = positionHand_Current;
            hand.transform.localScale = scaleHand_Current;
            hand.transform.localRotation = rotationHand_Current;
        }
    }

    if (handUseAnimationTimer <= 0.0f)
    {
        if (playerUnity.player.input.moveDirection.magnitude > 0.0f)
        {
            handMovementTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            float deltaY = Mathf.Sin(handMovementTimer * 10) * 0.02f;
            float deltaX = Mathf.Sin(handMovementTimer * 10) * 0.01f;

            hand.transform.localPosition = positionHand_Current + new Vector3(deltaX, deltaY, 0.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            handMovementTimer = 0.0f;
            hand.transform.localPosition = positionHand_Current;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (currentObjectInHand != null)
        {
            float deltaRotation = Mathf.Sin(handUseAnimationTimer * 2.0f * Mathf.PI) * 30;

            hand.transform.localPosition = positionHand_Current;

            switch (currentObjectInHand.definition.type)
            {
                case CWDefinition.DefinitionType.Tile:
                    hand.transform.localRotation = rotationHand_Current * Quaternion.Euler(deltaRotation, 0, 0);
                    break;

                case CWDefinition.DefinitionType.Item:
                    hand.transform.localRotation = rotationHand_Current * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, deltaRotation);
                    break;
            }
        }

        handUseAnimationTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (handUseAnimationTimer <= 0.0f)
        {
            hand.transform.localRotation = rotationHand_Current;
            handUseAnimationTimer = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}

private float userActionCooldown;

private void UpdateUserActions()
{
    if (playerUnity.gameManagerUnity.State == GameManagerUnity.GameManagerUnityState.GAME ||
        playerUnity.gameManagerUnity.State == GameManagerUnity.GameManagerUnityState.PAUSE)
    {
        Vector3 cameraPos = playerUnity.transform.position + playerUnity.GetLocalHeadPosition();
        Vector3 cameraFwd = playerUnity.mainCamera.transform.forward;

        CubeWorld.Utils.Graphics.RaycastTileResult raycastResult = CubeWorld.Utils.Graphics.RaycastTile(
                                                    playerUnity.player.world,
                                                    GraphicsUnity.Vector3ToCubeWorldVector3(cameraPos),
                                                    GraphicsUnity.Vector3ToCubeWorldVector3(cameraFwd),
                                                    10.0f,
                                                    true, false);

        if (userActionCooldown > 0.0f)
            userActionCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (userActionCooldown <= 0.0f)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) || Input.GetMouseButton(1))
            {
                ExecuteHandUseAnimation();

                userActionCooldown = 0.2f;
            }

            if (raycastResult.hit)
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
                {
                    if (raycastResult.position.x > 0 && raycastResult.position.x < playerUnity.player.world.tileManager.sizeX - 1 &&
                        raycastResult.position.z > 0 && raycastResult.position.z < playerUnity.player.world.tileManager.sizeZ - 1 &&
                        raycastResult.position.y > 0)
                    {
                        if (playerUnity.player.world.tileManager.HasTileActions(
                            raycastResult.position,
                            TileActionRule.ActionType.CLICKED))
                        {
                            playerUnity.player.world.gameplay.TileClicked(raycastResult.position);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (playerUnity.objectInHand != null)
                            {
                                switch (playerUnity.objectInHand.definition.type)
                                {
                                    case CWDefinition.DefinitionType.Item:
                                    {
                                        playerUnity.gameManagerUnity.fxManagerUnity.PlaySound("hitmetal", playerUnity.player.position);
                                        playerUnity.player.world.gameplay.TileHit(raycastResult.position, ((Item)playerUnity.objectInHand).itemDefinition);
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    default:
                                        playerUnity.gameManagerUnity.fxManagerUnity.PlaySound("hit", playerUnity.player.position);
                                        playerUnity.player.world.tileManager.DamageTile(raycastResult.position, 1);
                                        break;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
                {
                    if (playerUnity.objectInHand != null && playerUnity.objectInHand.definition.type == CWDefinition.DefinitionType.Tile)
                    {
                        TileDefinition tileDefinition = (TileDefinition) playerUnity.objectInHand.definition;
                        TilePosition tileCreatePosition = raycastResult.position + CubeWorld.Utils.Graphics.GetFaceNormal(raycastResult.face);

                        //Don't create tile on top of the world, because no triangles are drawn on the border!
                        if (tileCreatePosition.y < playerUnity.player.world.tileManager.sizeY - 1 &&
                            playerUnity.player.world.tileManager.IsValidTile(tileCreatePosition) &&
                            playerUnity.player.world.tileManager.GetTileSolid(tileCreatePosition) == false)
                        {
                            if (playerUnity.player.world.avatarManager.IsTileBlockedByAnyAvatar(tileCreatePosition) == false)
                            {
                                playerUnity.player.world.gameplay.CreateTile(tileCreatePosition, tileDefinition.tileType);

                                playerUnity.player.inventory.RemoveFromDefinition(tileDefinition, 1);

                                if (playerUnity.player.inventory.HasMoreOfDefinition(tileDefinition) == false)
                                    playerUnity.objectInHand = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateJump()
{
    playerUnity.player.input.jump = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
}

private void UpdateMovement()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    Vector3 dirWalk = transform.forward * v;
    Vector3 dirStrafe = transform.right * h;
    Vector3 dir = dirWalk + dirStrafe;
    dir.y = 0;
    dir.Normalize();

    playerUnity.player.input.moveDirection = GraphicsUnity.Vector3ToCubeWorldVector3(dir);
}

private void UpdateCameraRotation()
{
    if (Screen.lockCursor)
    {
        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
        {
            // Read the mouse input axis
            rotationYaxis += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
            rotationXaxis += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;

            rotationYaxis = ClampAngle(rotationYaxis, minimumX, maximumX);
            rotationXaxis = ClampAngle(rotationXaxis, minimumY, maximumY);

            Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationYaxis, Vector3.up);
            Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationXaxis, Vector3.left);

            playerUnity.mainCamera.transform.localRotation = originalCameraRotation * yQuaternion;
            transform.localRotation = originalPlayerRotation * xQuaternion;
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
        {
            rotationYaxis += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
            rotationYaxis = ClampAngle(rotationYaxis, minimumX, maximumX);

            Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationYaxis, Vector3.up);
            transform.localRotation = originalPlayerRotation * xQuaternion;
        }
        else
        {
            rotationXaxis += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationXaxis = ClampAngle(rotationXaxis, minimumY, maximumY);

            Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationXaxis, Vector3.left);
            playerUnity.mainCamera.transform.localRotation = originalCameraRotation * yQuaternion;
        }
    }
}

public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < -360F)
        angle += 360F;
    if (angle > 360F)
        angle -= 360F;
    return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this is a question best asked [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/topics/android.html).

However, being that it is unity I'm almost 100% sure that there is a built in controller script for android available to you as an option when you try to create a new project.

It sounds like you are creating something for PC and Android? Unless I am reading that incorrectly.

Either way there is definitely a controller script pre-made in Unity for PC projects and probably for android ones as well.